# Hibernate .hbm.xml files path in application?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having this lines of code from documentation

```
 private void createAndStoreEvent(String title, Date theDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Event theEvent = new Event();
        theEvent.setTitle(title);
        theEvent.setDate(theDate);
        session.save(theEvent);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Here I am not giving path of Event.hbm.xml file to Hibernate
and my doubt is which directory the hibernate refers to find 
Event.hbm.xml for mapping of Event.java entity class?.
Now i am saving Event and  Event.hbm.xml file in same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `Event.hbm.xml` should end up in the runtime classpath in the same package as the `Event.class` file. Something like `/WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar/` if it's a Web application. That being said, putting it in the `src` folder might be ok since your `IDE` should automatically put it in the `/WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar` during the build.

Answer (score 1):

In your hibernate-configuration xml, you should usually define your other hbm files as follows;

```
     <mapping resource="com/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: Is name of .hbm.xml file must be similar to entity class name?